Odoo : Window Actions create new object instead of opening the one targeted
I have something strange happening on Odoo 17 : Inside the sale confirm method I got a if condition that return an ir.actions.act_window action. Basicaly it saids that if a sale order is link to another sale order, go to this one to validate the whole order.
The problem is that this action create a new blank order instead of directing me to the one in question.
So here is the method :
def action_confirm_billing(self):
        for order in self:
            #If the order is link to another one, go to this one
            if order.order_id:
                #------------------------------
                # PROBLEM 
                #It create a blank order instead of directing to the parent one
                return {
                  "name": "My action",
                  'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                  'view_mode': 'form',
                  "res_model": "sale.order",
                  "views": [[False, "form"]],
                  "domain": [['id', '=', order.order_id.id]],
                  'target': 'current',
                }
                #------------------------------
            #everything below works fine
            order_ids = self.env['sale.order'].search([
                ('order_id', '=', order.id),
                ('state', 'in', ['draft','sent'])
            ])
            confirm = self.env['sale.order.confirm'].create({
                'name' : order.partner_id.name,
            })
            self.env['sale.order.confirm.line'].create({
                'confirm_id': confirm.id,
                'to_confirm': True,
                'order_id': order.id
            })
            for order_id in order_ids:
                self.env['sale.order.confirm.line'].create({
                    'confirm_id' : confirm.id,
                    'to_confirm' : True,
                    'order_id' : order_id.id
                })
        return {
            'name': _('Sale order confirm'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'sale.order.confirm',
            'view_id': self.env.ref('napsis_sale_order.sale_order_confirm_form').id,
            'target': 'new',
            'res_id': confirm.id,
        }


It is like the domain was not use.  What did I do wrong ?
Thanks a lot
